# cx_Oracle query results to nested dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary, cx-oracle

I need to create a set of dictionaries from Oracle query results.

My data is laid out into station ID, date, time, location, species, and catch weight.  For each species, there is a new line, while all the location, etc, data may be redundant.

First, I need to create a keyed dictionary by fieldname and value, such as stationID, date, etc so that when I call, say,

```
value[1]  (this being the station ID field)
```

I get

```
112
```

The end result is to conglomerate all of the "like" station ID's, dates, etc into one unique key-- with the resulting data (fish catch) being the values.

such as `[date,time,location, etc]`: cod 47, hake 31, dogfish 5

So far, to get the data parsed into individual keyed dictionaries by field name and then by line I have this:

```
desc=[d[0] for d in cursor.description]
field=[d[1] for d in cursor.description]
value=dict(zip(desc,field))   
result=[dict(zip(value,line)) for line in cursor]
print result[1]
```

However, if I try and call value, the field is simply the data type.. how can I get the actual data value?  And then nest that into the "result" dictionary that parses each individual sample?

Comment: I think you want `result[0]['station ID']` instead, where `result` is a list of dictionaries, one per result row, judging by your code attempt.

Comment: I see what you're saying...if I try this, however, I get a key error, though the inputted key is identical to what I used in the query...

Comment: Brilliant..thank you.  I knew I was over thinking it...

Comment: Actually, how can I print all the stations? result[???]['STATION']... I'm assuming it needs to be some "for" loop command?

Comment: Yes, or a list comprehension: `[r['STATION'] for r in result]`.

Comment: Thank you for putting up with my stupid questions.  Appreciate the help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are zipping together the wrong items. Zip only `desc` and `line`, you do not need to use the second item in the `cursor.description` tuples:

```
desc=[d[0] for d in cursor.description]
result=[dict(zip(desc, line)) for line in cursor]
```

Comment: Ok, that's what I thought.  That splits everything by sample... how can I then make each value callable?  A split?

Comment: If you want to aggregate data, why not have Oracle do that for you? You can query with a `GROUP BY` and have a `SUM()` column.

Comment: Oh! I don't know why I didn't think of this.  Can the results be read into a dictionary in the same manner?

Comment: Of course, all you are doing is processing standard cursor data.